# how to use declartive_Authorization in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have used `declartive_Authorization` in my app. But I want this is my rails engine as well without duplicating rules. Otherwise I have to use `declartive_Authorization` in rail engine again but that won't be DRY concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/tag/declarative_authorization/  .. does this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use your `engine` name with `Model` name in the `authorization_rules.rb` file.
`declarative_authorization` is work perfectly in `rails engine` as well.

For ex:

In `Rails engine`, there is one controller called

```
module MyEngine
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    filter_resource_access collection: [:index]
  end
end
```

so you defined rules as:

```
has_permission_on :my_engine_users, :to => [:index]
```